# Get-NetIPConfiguration run on remote machines and export to network share

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to run `Get-NetIPConfiguration` on multiple remote machines, take the information and export it to a text document on a network share. Preferably one text document that keeps adding all the Network card info from many servers beneath the last entry.

```
$file = "$env:computername$Filename.txt"
Get-NetIPConfiguration -detailed | Out-file -filepath '\\networkshare\Temp\$file'
```

*Results:* The NIC card info DOES export to a text file, called `"$File"`. I would like it to at least be labeled the localhost name.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use *double quotes* around the `-Filepath` parameter value to have your variable `$file` expanded.

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -detailed | Out-file -filepath "\\networkshare\Temp\$file"
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, that worked, really appreciate it